# Can't Access Terminal, Menus or Sidebar

Tags: command-line, upgrade, tty

I posted a while ago with this problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597113/14-10-upgrade-no-access-to-menus-or-sidebar, which I cannot find a workaround, especially as I can't access the Terminal via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>T</kbd>, and none of the login/passwords that I can think of will get me into the tty terminals.  I can't boot into safe mode either.

Does anyone know another way to open a terminal?  Is there a file on the computer I can access directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/295286)

Comment: Also, [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/173163/295286) might be simplest solution

Comment: Would that matter if I don't have nvidia anything in my machine?

Comment: Shouldn't. It happens regardless of the graphics card.  I have amd and it happened to me before.  Solved by installing gdm greeter then reinstalling lightdm

Comment: I tried all of those solutions, but none of them changed anything.  Some, I think, were outdated.  I also got an error message whenever I tried to use a line that included "-f".  Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd></kbd>. That should allow you to enter tty1. If that doesn't work, try <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd></kbd>, <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd></kbd>, etc. etc.

It will say something like:

`Ubuntu 14.10 ComputerName tty1`

`ComputerName Login:`

Type your username here and hit enter, and then your password.

You should be able to access tty and go from there.

Comment: Thanks!  I got there and I hate to admit that I just used the wrong username for the past week.

Comment: Any idea how to get the menus and launcher back from there?

Answer (score 0):

It might be an error in lightdm. Try installing gdm and uninstall lightdm and reboot and see if that works

If that doesnt work uninstall gdm and reinstall lightdm. Reboot. Then enter `unity-tweak-tool --reset` into tty. Reboot. See if that works

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately there is no change. I installed gdm, as we'll as installed the tweak tool and reset it, but nothing happened. Would it work to downgrade back to an earlier os that worked?

Comment: Are you using a nVidia graphics card?

Comment: I actually don't remember. It's been a couple of years. How would that affect it?

Comment: There are some bugs with the nVidia drivers that will do that

Comment: Will I see that if I take the cover off?

Comment: It should tell you on the GPU

Comment: You can also type `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: It is not nVidia. Looks like Radeon.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the newest xserver-xorg-video-intel package. Try downgrading to xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.99.910-0ubuntu1

Comment: I've never done anything like that - is it a basic command or is it more complicated? The articles I've seen online seem a bit contradictory.

Comment: let me get you the command

Comment: I actually just realized that fix for me was on a different version lol try the other fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this fix:

From a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

This will reinstall unity and reset the config.

If that doesn't work then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
rm --recursive /home/user/.config/dconf/user
```

but be aware that this solution will install all of the packages from ubuntu-desktop (including things like gedit, sound utility, archive managers etc.)

Comment: That's fine as long as it doesn't wipe files!

Comment: I doesnt. It only removes some config files

Comment: I'm getting "command line option 'f' [from -f] is not known" on both of those.

Comment: oops fixed the commands

Comment: I got the same message with -rf, ie not recognizing r from -rf ?