# Problems updating the system

Tags: updates

super newbie to ubuntu here. I was trying to download a chemistry program on Ubuntu 14.04 but in the software installation there were some errors and I opted for updates. Then slowly all the icons disappeared and i freaked out and logged out. On logging back in, i just found the Icons on desktop and nothing else. I pulled the power plug and then logged into TTY1 i tried following some advice here but it kept asking me to update to the newer version of ubuntu, which I did and its taking a long time now. 
Am I going to loose the data from my computer now? Or is it normal? Thanks for your patience with the question. 
Links of advice followed:
[Can't Access Terminal, Menus or Sidebar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/602549/cant-access-terminal-menus-or-sidebar)

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the link to (or details of) the "*advice here*" you followed.

Comment: Done. Please take a look. Thank you. Although, I do think that it might have been a bug in the system which was being updated. But not at all sure of this.

Comment: You are not telling us the whole story - installing software does not usually prompt you to update.

Comment: Hello there, I was a super newbie and I learnt over the last week how to do what I was asking and it turns out I had blown the unity and I re-installed ubuntu from scratch and it fixed the problem. Thank you all.